# Error after uninstalling npm packages

Tags: npm, npm-install

I have uninstalled the npm packages 'grunt-cli' and 'tsd' using the command:

```
sudo npm uninstall -g grunt-cli 
sudo npm uninstall -g tsd
```

But now, when I list all npm packages:

```
npm -g ls --depth=0
```

I get this error. There is no such file or directory. This is correct since I just uninstalled them...

```
/usr/local/lib
├── bower@1.7.1
├── browserify@12.0.1
├── express-generator@4.13.1
├──  error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli/package.json
├── npm@3.5.3
├──  error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/tsd/package.json
└── typescript@1.8.9
```

Why do I get this error? How to completely remove grunt-cli and tsd? What does ENOENT mean? (tried googling it...)

Comment: ENOENT means E (error) NO (no) ENT (entry), or in other words, "file not found". Does it help if you run npm cache clean?

Comment: A documented issue: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/11015

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following directories are still there by an accident probably, in spite of you ran `npm uninstall` command.

- `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli`
- `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/tsd`

In this case, you need to remove them manually by `rm -r` command:

```
$ rm -r /usr/local/lib/node_modules/tsd
$ rm -r /usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli
```

Also, you should check the command aliases still exist or not. Command names are
[tsd](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/tsd/blob/master/package.json#L42) and [grunt](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-cli/blob/master/package.json#L15), just check and remove them if they exist.

```
$ which tsd <= check command path
/usr/local/bin/tsd <= if it exist
$ rm /usr/local/bin/tsd <= remove it

$ which grunt <= check command path
/usr/local/bin/grunt <= if it exist
$ rm /usr/local/bin/grunt <= remove it
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `which grunt-cli` to locate the grunt-cli folder and then run `sudo rm grunt-cli`

Do the same for tsd.